# Is every complex polynomial of two variables a closed map in the topological sense?

Tags: general-topology

I was able to prove that given a polynomial $P(z) = a_0 + a_1z^1 + \cdots + a_mz^m$, $P(F)$ is closed if $F$ is.  Here's a quick summary of that proof:

Given a bounded sequence $\{P(x_n)\} \subset P(F)$ with $P(x_n) \to y$, we know that $\{x_n\}$ must be bounded as the inverse image of a bounded set is bounded for a polynomial of one variable.  Thus we have a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$; $F$ closed $\implies x \in F \implies P(x) = y \in P(F)$, completing the proof.

---

I'm wondering if the same is true for a polynomial of two variables.  My intuition was that it isn't true; the proof above can't be extended because the inverse image of a bounded set is no longer bounded.  For instance if the polynomial is $P(z,w) = zw$, then $P^{-1}(\{1\})$ is a pair of hyperbolas (when restricting $z,w \in \mathbb{R}$).  Despite this, I am unable to come up with a counterexample.  Is it the case that a polynomial of two variables is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your polynomial mapping $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C:(z,w)\mapsto zw$ is not closed. The discrete closed set $\{(\frac{1}{n^2},n):n\ge1\}$ is mapped onto $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\ge1\}$, which is not a closed set. Note that (non-constant) polynomial mappings $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C$ are always surjective. In higher dimensions one can use *blow-ups*. For instance, $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C^2:(z,w)\mapsto (z,zw)$ is not closed (as the preceding example). This mapping is not surjective: the (non-closed) image contains no point $(0,w)\ne(0,0)$. A more delicate example is the mapping $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C^2$ given by $f(z,w)=(zw-1,(zw-1)z^2-w)$,  which has the (non-closed) image: $f(\mathbb C^2)=\mathbb C^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how about a polynomial from $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You're right to ask for more! I've edited correspondingly.